# Extremely slow boot up - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: boot, virtualbox, network-manager, dns, avahi

I'm running:

```
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:printing-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

My boot up is very slow indeed. There are multiple services that fail to start:

```
grep -i fail boot.log|sort|uniq -d -c
      6 [FAILED] Failed to start Authorization Manager.
     20 [FAILED] Failed to start Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
     14 [FAILED] Failed to start Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.
      7 [FAILED] Failed to start Hostname Service.
    320 [FAILED] Failed to start Login Service.
      3 [FAILED] Failed to start Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles.
     21 [FAILED] Failed to start Modem Manager.
    392 [FAILED] Failed to start Network Manager.
     19 [FAILED] Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
      5 [FAILED] Failed to start Network Service.
     17 [FAILED] Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
      5 [FAILED] Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
     19 [FAILED] Failed to start Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -).
     10 [FAILED] Failed to start Samba NMB Daemon.
     16 [FAILED] Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
      3 [FAILED] Failed to start Session c1 of user peterbrooks.
     38 [FAILED] Failed to start Start TightVNC server at startup.
      5 [FAILED] Failed to start Thermal Daemon Service.
      8 [FAILED] Failed to start Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures.
      3 [FAILED] Failed to start User Manager for UID 1000.
     21 [FAILED] Failed to start WPA supplicant.
     16 [FAILED] Failed to start vboxadd.service.
     19 [FAILED] Failed to start vncserver.service.
      3 [DEPEND] Dependency failed for Wait for Network to be Configured.
```

It says the boot is still running:

```
systemd-analyze blame
Bootup is not yet finished. Please try again later.
```

Even though:

```
uptime
 12:41:22 up 58 min,  3 users,  load average: 0.61, 0.78, 3.65
```

The first error in boot.log is:

```
[  OK  ] Started Thermal Daemon Service.
[  OK  ] Started Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down.
[FAILED] Failed to start Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
See 'systemctl status avahi-daemon.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start WPA supplicant.
See 'systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start Login Service.
```

If I look at the Avahi report:

systemctl status avahi-daemon.service
* avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sat 2018-12-22 11:46:59 SAST; 56min ago
  Process: 654 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/avahi-daemon -s (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 654 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Status: "avahi-daemon 0.7 starting up."

```
Dec 22 11:46:53 govern avahi-daemon[654]: Server startup complete. Host name is govern.local. Local service cookie is 246024952.
Dec 22 11:46:57 govern systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Dec 22 11:46:57 govern avahi-daemon[654]: Got SIGTERM, quitting.
Dec 22 11:46:57 govern avahi-daemon[654]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s3.IPv6 with address fe80::a00:27ff:fe56:5727.
Dec 22 11:46:57 govern avahi-daemon[654]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s3.IPv4 with address 10.0.1.10.
Dec 22 11:46:58 govern avahi-daemon[654]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface lo.IPv6 with address ::1.
Dec 22 11:46:58 govern avahi-daemon[654]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface lo.IPv4 with address 127.0.0.1.
Dec 22 11:46:58 govern avahi-daemon[654]: avahi-daemon 0.7 exiting.
Dec 22 11:46:59 govern systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Dec 22 11:46:59 govern systemd[1]: Failed to start Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
```

Any idea of what is going wrong?